# How to use Array index in Ludo board

Tags: java, android, animation, imageview, coordinates

I just want to translate an image(Tokens) from bottom to top, left to right in **Ludo board** using animation. For this I have taken **coordinates** of every ImageView from where every token (red, blue, yellow, green colors) will move, but now I am stuck; what should i do next? I'm new to Android animation. How could I do that?

This is my Array Index code:

```
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.start );
    double aPowersOfTwo[] = new double[60];
    aPowersOfTwo[0]=Math.pow(81,263);
    aPowersOfTwo[1]=Math.pow(50,262);
    aPowersOfTwo[2]=Math.pow(50,231);
    aPowersOfTwo[3]=Math.pow(80,227);
}
```

my java code for yellow token is

```
switch(rand.nextInt(6) + 1)

    {
    case 1:

        diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_one);
        yellowToken.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.yellow_token9:
                    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,80,0,48);
                    animation.setDuration(1500);
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                    yellowToken.startAnimation(animation);
                    yellowToken.setVisibility(0);


                    break;
            }   
        }});

    case 2:
        diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_two);
        Log.d("dice", "2");
        break;
    case 3:

        diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_three);
        Log.d("dice", "3");
        break;

    case 4:

        diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_four);
        Log.d("dice", "4");
        break;
    case 5:

        diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_five);
        Log.d("dice", "5");
        break;
    case 6:

        diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_six);
        yellowToken.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.yellow_token9:
                    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,80,0,48);
                    animation.setDuration(1500);
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                    yellowToken.startAnimation(animation);
                    yellowToken.setVisibility(0);
                    break;
            }
        }});
```

and my xml code is

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/yellow_token9"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
android:layout_marginTop="222dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@drawable/yellow"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you storing all coordinate in array but you are using a wrong method Math.pow(x,y) it is used for x to the power y.so you should use 2-d array to store all coordinates.after doing this you can use this concept to develop this game-

Example-

if dice will display "1" you should increase your index by "1" and that coordinate pass in your

TranslateAnimation() method.

and then according to index number move them to the right position.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since I have developed this game, I am assuming that on the throw of dice, the tokens will move automatically, which will take away the magic of moving the coins but if not and you want to animate the movement upon touch then it is okay.
2. Another thing that I noticed is the size of the array - should be 64 unless I am missing something. You can check out my blog for an image of the board. http://ravichandranjv.blogspot.in

If you are using an imageView as a token, can you use drag-drop which also has animation possibilities? Of course, as you know, given your limited view in the question, it is difficult to provide you with ready code unless you have a specific answer in mind.

Comment: According to dice number i want to increase Array-index, so that on the click of image view i can use translate animation and also i am not getting how we can use this Array in translateAnimation().

Comment: Because we give x, y coordinates of the token's of initial positions like this example yellowToken.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     switch(v.getId()){
     case R.id.yellow_token9:
      Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,80,0,48);
      animation.setDuration(1500);
      animation.setFillAfter(true);
      yellowToken.startAnimation(animation);
      yellowToken.setClickable(false);
      yellowToken.startAnimation(animation);
      break;

Comment: so how can we give index coordinates in translateAnimation().

Comment: Sorry for responding so late, i was away from this forum. i wish it had an email notifications setting. Your switch condition v.getId() is not getting evaluated or used, R.id.yellow_token case has nothing to do with the condition. you have not evaluated the v.getId()